# Mongodb: Trying to find all documents with specific subdocument field, why is my query not working?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is an example of a document from the collection I am querying

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.research.findOne({_id: 'Z2zzA7dx6unkzKiSn'})
{
    "_id" : "Z2zzA7dx6unkzKiSn",
    "_userId" : "NtE3ANq2b2PbWSEqu",
    "collaborators" : [
        {
            "userId" : "aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "new one",
    "pending" : {
        "collaborators" : [ ]
    }
}
```

I want to find all documents within this collection with either _userId: 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4' or from the collaborators array, userId: 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'

So I want to look though the collection and check if the _userId field is 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'. If not then check the collaborators array on the document and check if there is an object with userId: 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'.

Here is the query I am trying to use:

```
db.research.find({$or: [{_userId: 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'}, {collaborators: {$in: [{userId: 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'}]}}] })
```

It does not find the document and gives me a syntax error. What is my issue here? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator is basically a simplified version of [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) but you really only have one argument here so you should not even need it. Use dot notation instead:

```js
db.research.find({
    '$or': [
        { '_userId': 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'},
        { 'collaborators.userId': 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'}
    ] 
})
```

If you need more than one value then use `$in`:

```js
db.research.find({
    '$or': [
        { '_userId': 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4'},
        { 'collaborators.userId': { 
            '$in': ['aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4','aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX5']
        }}
    ] 
})
```

Comment: im still a bit confused. I was using the $in operator because collaborators is an array of objects. If I am looking for an object in the collaborators array to have a key userId: 'aTPzFad8DdFXxRrX4' will the query still work? I thought using 'collaborators.userId' means that collaborators isnt an array but only has one subkey

Comment: @nearpoint MongoDB and in fact minimongo as well both allow you to notate a field within an array using the "dot notation" form. So rather than specify like `"collaborators": { "userId":` you do it as shown above. `$in` is not exclusive to arrays, but a list of values that could possibly match. That is why it is basically a simple version of `$or`